# Count of primes in integer factorization

Tags: algorithm, math, integer, primes

I wonder if there are any algorithms that can count or predict the number of primes in integer factorization. Not to find them, just compute their quantity. For example, for integer 198, the output is 4, because 198 contains 4 primes (2, 3, 3, 11). Is this possible in some efficient way? Some ideas?

Comment: Since my answer is not correct (see the comment under my answer) according to a good definition of "efficient", you should remove your acceptance of my answer so I can delete it. You also may want to explain more what you mean by "efficient'. Would an algorithm polynomial in the number of digits of the number be sufficient? (I do not know of such an algorithm.)

Comment: This question belongs on [maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The function that computes the number of distinct prime factors of an integer is known to number theorists as the ω (omega) function, so ω(198) = 3 for the primes 2, 3 and 11 (multiplicities of primes are ignored in computing ω). It can be computed by an inverse Möbius transform. A good place to start reading is [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DistinctPrimeFactors.html). Be prepared for some hairy greek-letter math.